# FFmpeg not adding thumbnail to last fragment

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails, h.265

I'm using this command to h265 encode a live video from a Blackmagic DeckLink card:

```
ffmpeg \
    -format_code 4k29 -f decklink -i "DeckLink 8K Pro (1)" \
    -c:v hevc_nvenc \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -b:v 20M -minrate 10M -maxrate 40M -bufsize 1M \
    -tag:v hvc1 \
    -g 12 \
    -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 1800 -strftime 1 "nvenc-%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S.mp4"
```

It works pretty well, but the last segment has no thumbnail (or Ubuntu fails to display it in the file explorer). I stop FFmpeg using CTRL-C.

Is there anything I can do (without adding the thumbnail to the last file using a second command)?

Comment: It is probably related to the CTRL-C. Does the last segment file played correctly and only the thumbnail is missing (or the last segment video file is corrupted)? Have you tried using different version of FFmpeg?

Comment: Yes the file plays correctly, and I'm using the latest version that I compiled last week or so. Is there another way than CTRL-C?

Comment: According the [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722624/how-to-stop-ffmpeg-remotely), CTRL-C is the clean way to stop FFmpeg (for "Newer versions of FFmpeg"). I was asking about other versions because there might be a bug in FFmpeg. For testing, you can define the recording time from advance using `-t` argument. I don't know enough about Ubuntu thumbnail mechanism... According the [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057/refresh-thumbnails-in-nautilus), executing `touch *` may help.

Comment: Thanks, but touching the file or deleting the ~/.cache/thumbnails didn't help. I'm not sure how the -t option could help? You mean I should use it to overwrite the file duration and see if Nautilus then works? For what it's worth, macOS has no problem displaying the thumbnail, so all the needed info is in the file.

Comment: Use `-t 10`  for 10 seconds recording for example. Instead of CTRL-C, FFmpeg stops after 10 seconds. (just for checking if the last file gets a thumbnail or not). It's not going to solve the issue... For testing, you may also try "re-muxing" the file: `ffmpeg -i in_file_name.mp4 -c copy -tag:v hvc1 out_file_name.mp4` (just in case there is something wrong with the file).

Comment: Oh I see thanks! indeed it won't solve the problem, but I'll give it a try.